arabic font with itext7 and thymeleaf
i want to create an arabic pdf, but i have this problem:

my code:
FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider(false, false, false);

fontProvider.addFont("/police/Amiri-bold.ttf");
ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
converterProperties.setFontProvider(fontProvider);

converterProperties.setBaseUri("http://localhost:8080");
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(cpar, pdfDoc, converterProperties);
pdfDoc.close();

i use itext7 v7.2.5 and html2pdf v4.0.5
the result must be like that:

I tried to use pdfcalligraph but it's not free!

"I tried to use pdfcalligraph but it's not free!" - It may not be free but without it iText does not offer support for scripts like Arabic. Well, of course you can try and add a similar functionality to iText. There is a library ICU4J which might be helpful for that but I've never had the need to try and use it.
